# Doctrine possible to reverse engineer inverse associations?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have database with about 100 tables and I'm using Doctrine 2 as my Data Mapper. I successfully generated entities for my tables, however, I noticed that many-to-one relationships didn't generate bidirectionally. Only many-to-one part of the relation generates, the one-to-many does not.

For instance in my `Company` entity I have

```
/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *   @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $user;
```

but I don't have anything pointing to the `Company` entity in `User`. 
I am aware that Doctrine doesn't do this OOTB [it says so in their documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#convert-mapping-information) but I was wondering if there is a way to get around this limitation.

Writing 300+ relations by hand is a task I don't want to undertake.

Is there perhaps an alternative Data Mapper library for PHP that can solve this for me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) because it generated everything wonderfully, albeit I ended up with some very large files (14k LoC).

It seems there simply isn't a PHP ORM that does everything right.